# Creating \x Single Char Hex Values in Python

Tags: python

How do you dynamically create single char hex values?

For instance, I tried

```
a = "ff"
"\x{0}".format(a)
```

and

```
a = "ff"
"\x" + a
```

I ultimately was looking for something like

```
\xff
```

However, neither of the combinations above appear to work.

Additionally, I was originally using `chr` to obtain single char hex representations of integers but I noticed that `chr(63)` would return `?` (as that is its ascii representation).

Is there another function aside from `chr` that will return `chr(63)` as `\x_ _` where `_ _` is its single char hex representation? In other words, a function that only produces single char hex representations.

Comment: `chr(31)` gives `'\x1f'` on my machine. Why do you care about the print out of it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to display the hexadecimal representation of a character, or generate the corresponding ascii character from a hex string?

Comment: Sorry, it was char(63) and was hoping it would look like '0x3f'
. My mistake. I'm trying to generate a large string of hexadecimal representations based on integers that I have been given. (ex: "\xeb\x1b"). However, I needed to create individual hexadecimal representations to form the larger string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `\x{0}`, Python escapes `x` and thinks that the next two characters will be hexa-decimal characters, but they are actually not. Refer the table [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

> ```
> \xhh  Character with hex value hh (4,5)
> ```
>
> 4 . Unlike in Standard C, exactly two hex digits are required.
>
> 5 . In a string literal, hexadecimal and octal escapes denote the byte with the given value; it is not necessary that the byte encodes a character in the source character set. In a Unicode literal, these escapes denote a Unicode character with the given value.

So, you have to escape `\` in `\x`, like this

```
print "\\x{0}".format(a)
# \xff
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `str.decode` with `'hex'` encoding:

```
In [204]: a.decode('hex')
Out[204]: '\xff'
```

Besides, `chr` returns a single-char string, you don't need to worry about the output of this string:

```
In [219]: c = chr(31)

In [220]: c
Out[220]: '\x1f'

In [221]: print c #invisible printout


In [222]:
```